# Replace values in a sequence

Tags: clojure, sequence

I'm having problems creating a function that replaces all occurrences of a value in a sequence.

Example: replace 'a' to 'z'; input:

```
((a b) f ((a b c) (e r) a) a)
```

expected output:

```
((z b) f ((z b c) (e r) z) z)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`prewalk-replace` is slightly simpler than @mobyte's answer if you're strictly swapping one value for another:

```
(def thing '( (a b) f ( (a b c) (e r) a ) a ))

(use '[clojure.walk :only [prewalk-replace]])

(prewalk-replace {'a 'z} thing)
; ((z b) f ((z b c) (e r) z) z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(use '[clojure.walk :only (postwalk)])

(postwalk #(if (= % 'a) 'z %) '( (a b) f ( (a b c) (e r) a ) a ))
-> ((z b) f ((z b c) (e r) z) z)
```